# Уместны ли на сайте не очень приличные логины

Tags: обсуждение

Как вы считаете, уместен ли здесь термин г**но-код, и умесны ли здесь  соответствующие изображениями (Например ник shit_coder)? Я понимаю что есть такой сайт, и возможно есть представители любящие это течение... но всё же?

Comment: А вопрос у него меж тем очень хороший: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/670236/213987

Comment: @AK пусть живёт? Или пусть меняет аватарку и/или ник?

Comment: @nick_n_a ник ему придётся сменить. В худшем случае, модераторскими силами. При условии, что модераторы сочтут его достаточно оскорбительным.

Comment: @D-side почему придется?  и чем он оскорбителен для других пользователей?

Comment: @Nikita речь не об оскорбительности, а о нецензурности. Смотрите придублированный вопрос.

Comment: Вопрос пусть однозначно живёт.

Comment: нажал на капу..